# how to write excel formula check row and return one value?

Tags: excel

I have data which has null and different values. I want to write a formula which check the row and if all values of row are NULL should give the result 1 otherwise 0. Can anyone help to write the formula

Comment: `=1*(COUNTA(A1:Z1)=0)`

Comment: The above will only work if the cells are truly null, and not null as the result of a formula in the cell.  If the cells have formulas then a different formula will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim neValues As Range, neFormulas As Range 

On Error Resume Next 
Set neValues = ActiveCell.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants)
Set neFormulas = ActiveCell.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)
On Error Goto 0 

If neValues Is Nothing And neFormulas Is NothingApplication.CountA(ActiveCell.EntireRow)=0 Then 
    MsgBox "Nothing There" 
Else 
    MsgBox "Something's There" 
End If
```

Check http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=26509 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give us much details but I think the COUNTBLANKS (range) formula should be what you need.

EDIT
In ur specific cade i would try:
=IF (CountBlanks (range)=columns (range), 0, 1)